# Prove that $Dom(S \circ R )= Dom (R)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Suppose R is a relation from A to B and S is a relation from B to C. Also given that $Ran (R) \subseteq Dom (S) $. Prove that $Dom(S \circ R )= Dom (R)$

Now Let $x \in Dom (S \circ R) \iff \exists b \in B$  s.t $(x,b) \in R$ and $(b,y) \in S$ $\iff x \in Dom(R)$.

Conversely,

Let $x \in Dom(R) \iff \exists b \in B (x,b) \in R$. Since $Dom(R) \subseteq Dom(S)$. so $b \in Dom(S)$ and hence $\exists y \in C$ $s.t (b,y) \in S$. So if $x \in Dom(S)$ , then $(x,b) \in R and (b,y) \in S$ for some $b$ and $y$. So $x \in Dom (S)$.

Please someone verify my proof as i donot have confidence especially in converse part.

Thanks

Comment: @ArnaudD. So is my proof correct?

Comment: It would be if you replaced the equivalences ($\Leftrightarrow$) with implications ($\Rightarrow$).